# Where exactly is a model object created in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute, request-mapping

After going through some tutorials and initial document reading from the docs.spring.org reference I understood that it is created in the controller of a POJO class created by the developer.
But while reading this I came across the paragraph below:

> An `@ModelAttribute` on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model. Once present in the model, the argument's fields should be populated from all request parameters that have matching names. This is known as data binding in Spring MVC, a very useful mechanism that saves you from having to parse each form field individually.
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Pet pet) {
>    
> }
> ```
>
> <sup>[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)</sup>

In the paragraph what is most disturbing is the line:

> "If not present in the model ... "

How can the data be there in the model? (Because we have not created a model - it will be created by us.)

Also, I have seen a few controller methods accepting the `Model` type as an argument. What does that mean? Is it getting the `Model` created somewhere? If so who is creating it for us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model.

The paragraph describes the following piece of code:

```
if (mavContainer.containsAttribute(name)) {
    attribute = mavContainer.getModel().get(name);
} else {
    // Create attribute instance
    try {
        attribute = createAttribute(name, parameter, binderFactory, webRequest);
    }
    catch (BindException ex) {
        ...
    }
}
...
mavContainer.addAllAttributes(attribute);
```

<sup>(taken from [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor#resolveArgument`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html#resolveArgument-org.springframework.core.MethodParameter-org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer-org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest-org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory-))</sup>

For every request, Spring initialises a [`ModelAndViewContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html) instance which records model and view-related decisions made by [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html)s and [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html)s during the course of invocation of a controller method.

A newly-created [`ModelAndViewContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html) object is initially populated with [flash attributes](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-flash-attributes) (if any):

```
ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer = new ModelAndViewContainer();
mavContainer.addAllAttributes(RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request));
```

**It means that the argument won't be initialised if it already exists in the model.**

To prove it, let's move to a practical example.

The `Pet` class:

```
public class Pet {
    private String petId;
    private String ownerId;
    private String hiddenField;

    public Pet() {
         System.out.println("A new Pet instance was created!");
    }

    // setters and toString
}
```

The `PetController` class:

```
@RestController
public class PetController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/internal")
    public void invokeInternal(@ModelAttribute Pet pet) {
        System.out.println(pet);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit")
    public RedirectView editPet(@ModelAttribute Pet pet, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        System.out.println(pet);
        pet.setHiddenField("XXX");

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("pet", pet);
        return new RedirectView("/internal");
    }

}
```

Let's make a POST request to the URI `/owners/123/pets/456/edit` and see the results:

```
A new Pet instance was created!
Pet[456,123,null]
Pet[456,123,XXX]
```

---

```
A new Pet instance was created!
```

Spring created a [`ModelAndViewContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/ModelAndViewContainer.html) and didn't find anything to fill the instance with (it's a request from a client; there weren't any redirects). Since the model is empty, Spring had to create a new `Pet` object by invoking the default constructor which printed the line.

```
Pet[456,123,null]
```

> Once present in the model, the argument's fields should be populated from all request parameters that have matching names.

We printed the given `Pet` to make sure all the fields `petId` and `ownerId` had been bound correctly.

```
Pet[456,123,XXX]
```

We set `hiddenField` to check our theory and redirected to the method `invokeInternal` which also expects a [`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html). As we see, the second method received the instance (with own hidden value) which was created for the first method.

Comment: That's really interesting. But about 'didn't find anything to fill the instance with': under what circumstances would it have found something? Doesn't it always need to create a new instance?

Comment: @daniu, if å redirect happens, a new instance of `ModelAndViewContainer` might be populated by the attributes extracted from `RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request)` that were set by the initialiser of redirection

Comment: @daniu Spring doesn't consider redirects to be game-changing enough to clear out the whole "context" for them. And it makes sense: in `invokeInternal`, I do expect the pet that was created for `editPet` if the redirect from it happened.

Comment: Oh, that's why you even added the `internal()` one, got it. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  Could you please answer for this as well "Also, I have seen a few controller methods accepting the Model type as an argument. What does that mean? Is it getting the Model created somewhere? If so who is creating it for us?"

Comment: How do you conclude for my question that where actually model object is created ?In Controller? In some other class?Or in both places Controller and that class ?

Comment: @JAVA I don't understand the question, it can't be created in the controller since it's an argument

Comment: @JAVA could you clarify it?

Comment: So model object(not referring form backing model object) is not created in controller ? It is created somewhere and passed as argument to which we are adding attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question i found few snippets of code with the help of @andrew answer. Which justify a ModelMap instance[a model object] is created well before our controller/handler is called for specific URL

```
 public class ModelAndViewContainer {

    private boolean ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect = false;

    @Nullable
    private Object view;

    private final ModelMap defaultModel = new BindingAwareModelMap();
      ....
      .....
   }
```

If we see the above snippet code (taken from spring-webmvc-5.0.8 jar). **BindingAwareModelMap**   model object is created well before.

For better Understanding adding the comments for the class **BindingAwareModelMap**

```
   /**
     * Subclass of {@link org.springframework.ui.ExtendedModelMap} that automatically removes
     * a {@link org.springframework.validation.BindingResult} object if the corresponding
     * target attribute gets replaced through regular {@link Map} operations.
     *
     * <p>This is the class exposed to handler methods by Spring MVC, typically consumed through
     * a declaration of the {@link org.springframework.ui.Model} interface. There is no need to
     * build it within user code; a plain {@link org.springframework.ui.ModelMap} or even a just
     * a regular {@link Map} with String keys will be good enough to return a user model.
     *
     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
      public class BindingAwareModelMap extends ExtendedModelMap {
      ....
      ....
     }
```